# Android, how to add to parameters to LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I want to add two parameters to LayoutParams:

```
 View bar1 = new View(this);
 bar1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_bar);
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(68, (int(aValue));

 relativeParams1.bottomMargin=50;
 Log.i(TAB, relativeParams1.debug(OUTPUT));
     linearLayout.addView(bar1, relativeParams1);
```

but only width and height is changing. The included logcat show me that

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams={ width=68, height=300 }
```

How do I change the margins too?

Comment: The LayoutParams should have a method setMargins(). Try using it instead of setting the field directly.

Comment: Also relativeParams1.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 50); is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the type of layout you are adding bar1 to, is it a LinearLayout ?
In that case, you can't use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams, you have to use LinearLayout.LayoutParams and, if I remember correctly, you don't have margins there.
So change the containing layout